# Installation of py3exiv2 on macOS Big Sur fails | ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyexiv2

I'm trying to install py3exiv2 on macOS Big Sur with

```
pip install py3exiv2
```

and

```
pip3 install py3exiv2
```

both of which yield

```
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in/private/var/folders/gf/g7tsgb6x4l9gyms1jm5kmlsc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-__dllgi9
```

Are there any workarounds for this issue?

I already have pyexiv2, exiv2 and boost.python running on Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar issue listed by Robert [here](https://www.rwardrup.com/install-py3exiv2-on-macos/) for macOS Catalina,

Installing dependencies using

```
brew install boost-python3 gexiv2 pygobject3
```

Then downloading the [py3exiv2 package](https://pypi.org/project/py3exiv2/#files)
and installing using

```
pip install py3exiv2-{version_number}.tar.gz
```

Works like a Charm on macOS Big Sur too!

Comment: The 1st link is broken (it points to this question). Please fix.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I'm on an M1 MacBook Pro. I still get the following error: 

"ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in /private/var/folders/9m/k2j6pg_95k9__bhyxsygz2540000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-otvmfouy"

Comment: @AmateurAardvark can you post the trace too

Comment: @Luke Sure - too long to post in comments & as I suspect this may be an issue specific to the M1, I've posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923219/installation-of-py3exiv2-fails-on-mbp-m1-macos-big-sur-installationerror-no

Comment: For M1 Macs you need to edit the setup.py to make this work again. I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923219/installation-of-py3exiv2-fails-on-mbp-m1-macos-big-sur-installationerror-no/72088586#72088586

Answer (score 0):

The answer which was marked correct no longer worked for me in MacOS catalina.  pip3 is not looking for the headers files in correct places. Check my answer here: https://answers.launchpad.net/py3exiv2/+question/700064

This is what fixed it for me:

To get around this problem do the following:

`brew install boost-python3 gexiv2 pygobject3`

After installing the dependencies, you'll face more errors. To get around those, set the corrext include and linker path and then install the module using pip.

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5_1/include/:/usr/local/opt/libssh/include/:/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.76.0/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5_1/lib"

 pip install py3exiv2
```

or if you are using pipenv

```
 CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5_1/include/:/usr/local/opt/libssh/include/:/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/ LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.76.0/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5_1/lib" pipenv install
```

Comment: This currently does not work for m1 macs which have exiv2 and other files in /opt/ instead of /usr/. See my answer here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923219/installation-of-py3exiv2-fails-on-mbp-m1-macos-big-sur-installationerror-no/72088586#72088586